# Conflicting Service Worker Scopes (broad vs. narrow)

Tags: scope, service-worker

Suppose we have a service worker `sw-main.js` which controls the home page.

> sw-main.js > scope is "/"

And let's say we have another service worker `sw-product.js` which controls the product page.

> sw-product.js > scope is "/product"

When we visit the home page, followed by the product page, both service workers are installed and activated.

**My question is:** When we are on the product page (scoped under `sw-product.js`), will the home page service worker (`sw-main.js`) interfere with `sw-product.js`'s behavior?

(Ideally, both service workers control the page, but `sw-product.js` has a narrower scope, matching only the product page, while the home page service worker `sw-main.js` has a broader scope.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each page can by controlled by at most one service worker. If multiple service workers are registered for an origin, and their scopes overlap, then the service worker with the longest-matching scope (i.e. the most specific scope match) will "win", and it will be the one that controls the page.

There's just one wrinkle that I want to clarify: once a service worker is in control of a client page, all of the HTTP requests that page makes will trigger the `fetch` handlers of the controlling service worker. If there is no `fetch` handler, or if there's a `fetch` handler but it doesn't call `event.respondWith()` for a given request, then the request will be made against the network, as if there were no service worker involvement. The request will **not** fall through to any other service workers that might also be registered. Only one service worker can handle a given request.

(The [other response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47141646/385997) might be describing behavior due to a HTTP redirect from `/product` to `/product/` or something like that, that made it look like the same request was being handled twice, when it was really two different HTTP requests.)

Answer (score 0):

I quickly checked it with Chrome 63.0.3239.2 add I got the following result:

/ => handled by sw.js

/product/ => handled by sw2.js

/other => handled by sw.js

For /product I got a strange behavior:
first sw.js handles the request, then sw2.js handles the request as well.

So the safest way to have no mixup is probably using the product url with an ending slash (/product/)